# Raspberry Terminal and SSH not working

Tags: ssh, fsck

I made a `fsck` on my Raspberry Pi and now it won't open the terminal (it's opening but there is a black screen and there is no `pi@raspberry` appearing). SSH opens, but the same thing happens.

`.bash_profile` only prints the "motd".

How can I fix this? I made many `fsck.ext4`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created /proc and other folders and It fixxed

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I don't see how it answers the question...And it's your question!

Comment: Fsck ra*ed  proc and other emply folders that kernel needs soo kernel cant mount it (proc, sys, ...) and i created that folders it fixxed and that "-1" to your ...

Answer (score 1):

use another linux box to read and backup your favourite files from SD card, then reimage fresh Raspbian build and put files back again, this might be the easiest and fastest way to recover from broken file system.

additional points if you use another, preferably new, SD card for the new image.

Comment: i got alotof server and configs on it like bind9.There is no way to fix only terminal ? because other apps running

Comment: @user1576186 if you can't get the terminal fixed, you can backup the configs and drop them onto your new install. everything should work exactly as it did before as long as you get all the config files.

Comment: but i have limited net in there. Can i get apps too ? http://i.imgur.com/DpcLTqH.png http://i.imgur.com/ZwA30QQ.png

Comment: /proc there is no file or dictory maybe this making error?